# Calling Tkinter Entry as Variable in another Script

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm stuck using an entry input as a variable in Tkinter. Currently I have a code that creates a textbox for the user to input a value:

`gui_test.py`"

```
from tkinter import *
class GUI:

    def __init__(self, window): 
       
        window.title("HyPep 1.0")
        window.geometry("700x700")
#ppm error

        ttk.Label(window, text='Input ppm error threshold:').grid(column=0,row=8)
        ppm_err = Entry(window)
        ppm_err.grid(column=1,row=8)
        err_tol = ppm_err.get()      



        ttk.Button(window, text = "Analyze", command = window.destroy).grid(row = 10,column=1, ipadx=5, ipady=15)

window = tkinter.Tk()
gui = GUI(window)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    window.mainloop()
```

I have another script, `User_input.py`

```
from gui_test import err_tol

ppm_err_gui = err_tol
print(ppm_err_gui)
```

This returns:
`ImportError: cannot import name 'err_tol' from 'gui_test'`

What am I doing wrong?

ETA: more thorough code example.

Comment: provide a [mre], the given code shouldn't produce that error, do you have `if __name__ == '__main__':` in `gui_test`? also `err_tol = ''` because you immediately get the input without the user having a change to enter anything, maybe you should consider [`tkinter.messagebox`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkMessageBox.html) module which provides ready functions for asking strings and numbers and it returns the value

Comment: @Matiss I updated my question to be a little more thorough. Currently GUI provides everything I need, I just need to be able to call the err_tol input value.

Comment: hint: err_tol is a local variable that is only visible inside `__init__`.

Comment: How would I go about making it visible outside? I pulled the code back one indent but that didn't fix anything.

Comment: Usually, variables in a class that you want to work cross-method, or that you want other code to be able to use, are prefixed with `self.`. This makes sure that the variable doesn't get deleted at the end of the method. So you would change all occurrences of `err_tol` to `self.err_tol`. I also suggest you use `self.window` and `self.pm_err` inside your class as well.

Comment: Even making `err_tol` visible outside the function by changing it to `self.err_tol`, but its content is empty string because nothing is input during the assignment.